# Mapping data into a CSS grid - how do I return one element per grid square?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

Say that I'm building a CSS grid with three grid items, as a component in a react project.  I want to display data in each grid square, which is derived from the following array:

```
const applicants = [

  {name: 'James',
   age: 35,
   experience: 'none'
  },
  {name: 'Kate',
   age: 27,
   experience: 'intermediate'
  },
  {name: 'Henry',
   age: 32,
   experience: 'senior'
  }
]
```

I want to be able to display one name per grid square, however my problem is that each square is populated with **all** of the names, instead of one name being mapped to each square. How can I fix this? More code as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

const applicants = [

  {name: 'James',
   age: 35,
   experience: 'none'
  },
  {name: 'Kate',
   age: 27,
   experience: 'intermediate'
  },
  {name: 'Henry',
   age: 32,
   experience: 'senior'
  }
]

const displayName = () =>{
  return (
    <div>
      {
        applicants.map(item=> {
        return <h1>{item.name}</h1>
      })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default displayName
```

```
import React from 'react'
import displayName from './displayName'

const Grid = () => {
  return(
    <div className = 'grid-container'>
      <div className = 'grid-item'>
        <displayName/>
      </div>
    <div className = 'grid-item'>
        <displayName/>
      </div>
    <div className = 'grid-item'>
        <displayName/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Grid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be other way around. Kindly refer below.

```
const displayName = props => <h1>{props.name}</h1>
```

```
import React from 'react'
import displayName from './displayName'

const applicants = [

  {name: 'James',
   age: 35,
   experience: 'none'
  },
  {name: 'Kate',
   age: 27,
   experience: 'intermediate'
  },
  {name: 'Henry',
   age: 32,
   experience: 'senior'
  }
]

const Grid = () => {
  return(
    <div className = 'grid-container'>
      {
        applicants.map(item=> {
          return (<div className = 'grid-item'>
                   <displayName name={item.name}/>
                 </div>)
        })
      }
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not do the map on your `displayItem` const. Do it on the Grid and use it as a function component. Pass your array to a prop in `Grid` and then use `map` function on the prop.

```
import React from 'react'
import displayName from './displayName'

const Grid = (props) => {
  return(
      <div className = 'grid-container'>
      { props.data.map((d, i) => (
         <div className = 'grid-item'>
            <displayName name={d.name} />
         </div>
       )}
      </div>
   )
}


export default Grid
```

Doing this will likely solve your issues.

EDIT: Closing `div` tag of grid `div`

Comment: Also, React components should **always** start with a capital letter --> `<DisplayName />`